# Detecting memory leaks in nodejs

Tags: node.js

Are there some tools for detecting memory leaks in nodejs? And tell me about your experience in testing nodejs applications.

Comment: I read this blog and i find it helpful, http://dtrace.org/blogs/bmc/2012/05/05/debugging-node-js-memory-leaks/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The following tool should be useful for spotting memory leaks:

[node-inspector](https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector)

And there's also a tutorial to help you find memory leaks here:

https://github.com/felixge/node-memory-leak-tutorial

Answer (score 10):

In tracking down a memory leak I tried the above node-inspector.
As of April 2012 it was not updated to work with the contemporary node release v0.6.12
As such I found: https://github.com/c4milo/node-webkit-agent.
It was able to show heap snapshots for the newer V8 engine which wasn't supported by node-inspector.  In short order I was able to detect the leaking module (in may case loggly), I hope you have similar success!

Answer (score 6):

I could also recommend following sources:

1. following episodes of NodeUp, where profiling and memory leaks detection tools are discussed:

   - http://nodeup.com/twentyone
   - http://nodeup.com/fortyfive
2. This article - [Tracking Down Memory Leaks in Node.js – A Node.JS Holiday Season](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/11/tracking-down-memory-leaks-in-node-js-a-node-js-holiday-season/), which basically aggregates all widely known modules and techniques to track down memory leaks
3. For Mac OS - [Instruments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruments_%28application%29) tool could be helpful to debug native (C++) modules. It is not so sophisticated as SmartOS tools, but very easy to setup.

Answer (score 5):

**Method 1 -**
Node allows us to manually trigger Garbage Collection, and it is the first thing that we should do when trying confirm a memory leak. This can be accomplished by running Node with --expose-gc flag (i.e. node --expose-gc index.js). Once node is running in that mode, you can programmatically trigger a Garbage Collection at any time by calling global.gc() from your program.

You can also check the amount of memory used by your process by calling process.memoryUsage().heapUsed.

By manually triggering garbage collection and checking the heap used, you can determine if you in fact observing a memory leak in your program. Memory growth becomes even more evident as you do this test.

**Method 2 -**

3 Heap Dumps Method

Node’s --inspect flag landed in node version 6. This feature lets you debug and inspect your node process from within Chrome’s DevTools.

Simply start the application passing the --inspect flag:

`$ node --inspect index.js`

Follow the URL to the inspector and navigate to the memory tab.

DevTools Memory Tab

[image]
Here’s what we will do:

Hit the application with autocannon -c 1 -d 60 http://localhost:PORT
[ https://www.npmjs.com/package/autocannon ]
Take a heap snapshot after roughly 10 seconds, and again after 30 seconds.

Heap Snapshot Comparison
The comparison view shows us what has happened between snapshots. You can see a huge number of objects have been created or not being collected by the GC.

Please read these amazing articles to learn more.
They have been of great help to find & fix a leak :-

https://www.alexkras.com/simple-guide-to-finding-a-javascript-memory-leak-in-node-js/

https://www.nearform.com/blog/self-detect-memory-leak-node/

https://addyosmani.com/blog/taming-the-unicorn-easing-javascript-memory-profiling-in-devtools/

Answer (score 2):

I use Chrome dev tools and heapsnapshot file directly, not node-inspector or node-webkit-agent.

`require()` the **heapdump** module.

Send usr2 signal to the running nodejs process to get heapsnapshot file.

Load the heapsnapshot file on the profiles tab of Chrome dev tools.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the npm package Memwatch:

Take a look to the [Github repository](https://github.com/lloyd/node-memwatch) and the
[NPM source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memwatch)

Basically this package checks the memory heap usage right after a garbage collection is performed by the V8 engine, and give you a baseline of the actual memory usage.

Here's how I used it:

```
var memwatch = require('memwatch');

memwatch.on('leak', function(info) {
    console.log('Memwatch leak: ');
    console.log(info);
});

memwatch.on('stats', function(stats) {
    console.log.message('Memwatch stats: ');
    console.log(stats);
});
```

From the original documentation:

> The `'stats'` event, emitted occasionally, give you the data describing
>   your heap usage and trends over time.
>
> The `'leak'` event, is emitted when it appears your code is leaking
>   memory. It is usually executed when the heap size continously grows in
>   a short period of time.

Memwatch also provides a "HeapDiff" class to compute the heap state between two snapshots you can take in your functions.

It might be a good idea to have memwatch running in your stage environment, in order to track events causing the issue.

Comment: You need `memwatch-next` it supports the same calls.

Answer (score 0):

One good thing is 
https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-heapdump
very simple and you can view results in Chrome (because of same V8 engine in browser javascript and nodejs) and compare object sizes in memory at every moment you want.

And one more tip how to detect memory leak "manualy" or help to prevent it, is force garbage collector in some places of your code and see what happens.

Start your application with "node --expose-gc file.js" and anywhere in code you can use function gc(); to call garbage collection.