# Debugging memory leaks nodejs

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks

I'm trying to debug memory leaks in my production server.
I'm looking for node profilers but all the solutions I find require the v8-profiler ( https://github.com/dannycoates/v8-profiler ) which doesn't seem to work with the latest versions of node (linkage error: https://github.com/dannycoates/v8-profiler/issues/20 ).

Can you recommend other solutions?
(I realize that this is a duplicate of [Detecting memory leaks in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577704/detecting-memory-leaks-in-nodejs) but the solutions suggested there are not updated as well...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Nodetime](http://nodetime.com). It shows heap from the point of view of retainers, i.e. properties, array elements, etc. More info in this post [Detecting Memory Leaks in Node.js Applications](http://blog.nodetime.com/2012/07/detecting-memory-leaks-in-nodejs-apps.html)
. To install nodetime see [instructions](http://docs.nodetime.com/#installation-and-use), which is basically installing and requiring the nodetime package.