# Memory consumption in Node.js/Express application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, modulus, modulus.io

My application is running on one Modulus servo with 512 MB of memory.
A run of the app looks like this:

[image: modulus metrics]

As you can see, the memory rises during execution. But then it stays at 100% indefinitely, even if no further requests are made. I am concerned about the memory consumption of the app on repeated requests.

Is there something that I need to do in my Node.js/Express app to get memory consumption down again after a request finishes?

Currently, I only have this:

```
process.on("exit", function () {
    'use strict';
    if (mongoose && mongoose.connection) {
        mongoose.connection.close();
    }
});
```

Comment: The jump in memory coincides with a steep response time. Are you retrieving lots of data from MongoDB? If so, how exactly?

Comment: I would note that this is a confusing graph. It has 2 axis. The CPU axis goes to 100%. The memory graph scales by the maximum amount consumed in the time window. So you are not actually using 100% of the memory, the 100% label only applies to CPU usage.

Comment: I think you might be slightly colorblind.  The graph has two shades of green, and it's definitely the memory line that is pegged to the top.

Comment: Well, the spike and then staying there is perfectly explainable.  When V8 allocates memory, it just keeps it indefinitely for performance reasons.  Is this a problem for you?  You might need more memory for what you're doing, but we couldn't tell you for sure since we have no idea what your application does.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have memory leak.

Which version of Node.js you are using?

0.12 - Seems to consume more memory.

Check this answers for more,

[Detecting memory leaks in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577704/detecting-memory-leaks-in-nodejs)

Tutorial -- https://github.com/felixge/node-memory-leak-tutorial